# String comparison from XML failing

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently working on a project in PowerShell. The project downloads the NVD database XML, loops through a separate CSV for scan results from Nexpose, and pulls CVSS scores for each vulnerability identified with a CVE number.

It seems that matching the CVE number from the sheet (string) with the CVE number in the XML (also a string) is failing completely. The code i am using is below:

```
clear
[xml]$nvdxml = (New-Object system.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-recent.xml")
$nsmgr = New-Object System.XML.XmlNamespaceManager($nvdxml.NameTable)        
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('vuln','http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4')
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('cvss','http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-recent.xml')
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('df','http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0')
$nvdxml.SelectNodes('//vuln:product',$nsmgr) | out-null 
$nvdxml.SelectNodes('//vuln:vulnerable-configuration',$nsmgr) | out-null
$nvdxml.SelectNodes('//vuln:vulnerable-software-list',$nsmgr) | out-null
$nvdxml.SelectNodes('//default:nvd',$nsmgr) | out-null
$nvdxml.SelectNodes('//default:entry',$nsmgr) | out-null
$x = import-csv "test-report.csv" 
$items = @()

$x | where {$_."Vulnerability Test Result Code" -like "v*"} | %{
    $item = @{}
    $vid = $_."Vulnerability CVE IDs"
    $entry = ""
    $item["Vname"] = $_."Vulnerability Title"
    $item["VNode"] = $_."Asset IP Address"
    $item['VID'] = $vid
    $entry = $nvdxml.nvd.entry | where { $_."cve-id" -eq $vid } 
    $item['Score'] = $entry.cvss.base_metrics.score 
    $items += $item
    }
    $items
```

The $items array contains a vulnerability which has a CVE ID, but the string comparison is utterly failing. When I query for the object's type I get

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:25 char:19
+     $entry.GetType <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetType:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

When I assign a CVE ID to a string, and attempt to get the relevant vulnerability from the XML for that string, the comparison returns no results; yet, when I replace the variable with the quoted string of the same ID, the query returns the correct result. So, this would fail

```
$cveID = "CVE-2003-1567"
$nvdxml.nvd.entry | where { $_."cve-id" -eq $cveID }
```

However, this works fine

```
$nvdxml.nvd.entry | where { $_."cve-id" -eq "CVE-2003-1567" }
```

Any ideas? I have tried explicitly casting both $_."cve-id" and $cveID as String with the same results.

Comment: Either use the ISE to debug and fine what the value of $cveID is before that line, or simply put $cveID in the script on the line above $nvdxml.nvd.entry | ? ... It sounds to me like $cveID doesn't have the value you expect.

Comment: I am using ISE to debug, and have verified that $cveID has the correct value. I've even tried setting $cveID in the immediate window, and then executing the query against the XML normally and still fails.

Comment: Little hard to tell what's going on without the CSV file, so I'm speculating a bit here.  It looks like you're comparing two properties of the CSV file (i.e. `$_."cve-id"` and `$vid`).  Don't you want to compare one from the CSV and the other from the XML?  Also, based on the name, it looks like `$vid` might be an array (`$vid = $_."Vulnerability CVE IDs"`).  If that's true, then it looks like you're trying to compare a value to an array (i.e. `$_."cve-id" -eq $vid`).

Comment: I do indeed want to compare the data from the XML and CSV files. When I use `$nvdxml.nvd.entry | where { $_."cve-id" -eq $cveID }`, `$_."cve-id"` refers to the results of the piped output from `$nvdxml.nvd.entry`. Regarding `$vid` being an array, I don't see how that's possible. When I use `.gettype()` on `$vid`or `$_."Vulnerability CVE IDs"`, it returns a String type.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all the entries in a hashtable, then look it up via the CVE ID:

```
$entriesByID = @{ }
$nvdxml.nvd.entry | 
    ForEach-Object { $entriesByID[$_.id] = $_ }
```

Note that instead of using the `cve-id` element, I'm using the `id` attribute on the `event` element.

Then, you can look it each entry in the hashtable:

```
$entry = $entriesByID[$vid]
```

If you're married to your original approach, you may be running into namespace issues. I would try using `SelectNodes` instead of PowerShell's virtual XML object properties:

```
$entry = $nvdxml.SelectSingleNode('/nvd/entry[vuln:cve-id = "$vid"]')
# or
$entry = $nvdxml.SelectSingleNode('/nvd/entry[@id = "$vid"]')
```